# Задание атрибутов файла

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Не подскажете, как правильно работать с полями класса FileInfo. Пытаюсь установить атрибут, но ничего не получается... Прошу помощи..

```
FileAttributes ^attributes = gcnew File->GetAttributes("c:/Temp/testfile.txt");
if ((attributes & FileAttributes->ReadOnly) == FileAttributes->ReadOnly)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использование класса `FileInfo`:

```
FileInfo ^fileInfo = gcnew FileInfo(path);

if ((fileInfo->Attributes & FileAttributes::ReadOnly) == FileAttributes::ReadOnly) {
    // атрибут readonly установлен
}
else {
    // Устанавливаем атрибут
    fileInfo->Attributes = fileInfo->Attributes | FileAttributes::ReadOnly;
}
```

К полям перечисления обращаемся через двоеточие.

---

Для атрибута `read-only` в этом классе есть специальное свойство: `IsReadOnly`. Используя его, код можно упростить:

```
// проверяем атрибут
if (fileInfo->IsReadOnly)

// задаем атрибут
fileInfo->IsReadOnly = true;
```

А вот все остальные атрибуты (Hidden, Archive и прочие) придется проверять/устанавливать с помощью битовых операций.

---

Можно получать/задавать атрибуты напрямую:

```
FileAttributes attributes = File::GetAttributes(path);

if ((attributes & FileAttributes::ReadOnly) == FileAttributes::ReadOnly) {
    // атрибут readonly установлен
}
else {
    // Устанавливаем атрибут
    File::SetAttributes(path, attributes | FileAttributes::ReadOnly);
}
```

Методы `GetAttributes` и `SetAttributes` статические, поэтому используется двоеточие для их вызова.

`FileAttributes` - перечисление (enum), т. е. значимый тип. Указатель `^` для него не нужен.

Comment: не подскажете как правильно инициализировать  DateTime ^date1 = new DateTime(2008, 5, 1, 8, 30, 52)  на с++?

Comment: @Anna - задайте отдельный вопрос (создайте новую тему). Я вам все способы распишу. Длинновато получается для комментария.